# How can I hide my page source for my website?

Tags: html, css

I want to hide my page sources for my website. But I am having some problems to find the code that would hide my page sources. I am using HTML and CSS.

I have tried searching on Google, but I was unable to find it. I would appreciate if anyone could tell me that code to hide page sources.

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Forget it. Nobody will want to steal it anyway.

Comment: Shorter answer: Get rid of the page.

Comment: Don't waste your time. FYI, if I was a scriptkiddie/blackhat hacker and saw something like this that would make your site my newest target.

Comment: And Long answer: No matter what you try. Its still visible in some way

Comment: what data are you trying to protect btw and how ? the source of a page needs to be distributed ...

Comment: http://drpeterjones.com/hidden/hidden.php

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible. No matter how much JavaScript tricks you use (which, by the way, hide your site from search engines, too) - the browser will always build a proper DOM tree anyone can look at e.g. using firebug.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The source of your page is how the browser renders it. It's what your server returns when a request is made.

Any developer could create a web client, make the request, and simply dump the text to the screen...thus revealing your source code.

Answer (score 0):

You cant... The best thing you could do is obfuscate the html and css so people cant easy read it, but if they want there are some ways of getting your code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated and can't be used for every page you might think of, but think about using phantomjs to render your page on the server side and serve that instead of regular HTML. The complicated part is having your links or other media behave like they should.

Practically it's about impossible... and usually totally useless... Forget it!

Comment: Yay, serve an image that is totally inaccessible to search engines! Just like good old flash websites...